# How to run flyway clean and migration silently without don't mess on screen in Java / Clojure?

Tags: java, clojure, flyway

I use flyway clean and migration during tests and flyway print on my screen a lot of INFO. I don't want to see that, because it makes tests unclear. How can i turn off INFO log ONLY for flyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank your for your hints. What i exactly needed was:

```
(ns foo.fixtures
  (:import (java.util.logging Logger Level)))

(.setLevel (Logger/getLogger "org.flywaydb") Level/WARNING)

(defn wrap-test [tests]
  (reset-db)
  (tests))
```

It turn off INFO logs for flyway only in tests without any additional dependency.

Answer (score 1):

Solution based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/22371427/5277820:

You have to add [Log4J JAR](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/download.html) to your classpath.

Also you have to create a `log4j.properties` file like this:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, CONSOLE

log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern = %d [%t] %-5p %c- %m%n

log4j.logger.org.flywaydb=WARN
```

and add it to your classpath.

For more information read the [Log4J Manual](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html).

Since version 3.1 Flyway supports also SLF4J, see [Issue 834](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/834).